# Configuring Apache Shiro 1.7.0 with Springboot 2.4.0

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

I'm trying to add Apache shiro 1.7.0 as security manager bellow you will find my configuration class :

```
public class ShiroConfig {


    @Bean(name="shiroFilter")
    @DependsOn({"securityManager"})
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shirFilter(SecurityManager securityManager) {
        log.info("ShiroConfiguration.shirFilter()");
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/captcha", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/app/code/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("admin/**/page-query", "user");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/app/web/logout", "logout");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("admin/**/detail", "authc");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/403");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);

        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor(){
        LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor = new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
        return lifecycleBeanPostProcessor;
    }


    @Bean(name="ehCacheManager")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public EhCacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        log.info("ShiroConfiguration.getEhCacheManager()");
        EhCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCacheManagerConfigFile("classpath:ehcache-shiro.xml");
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean(name="adminRealm")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public AdminRealm adminRealm(EhCacheManager ehCacheManager) {
        AdminRealm adminRealm = new AdminRealm() ;
       
        adminRealm.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager);
        return adminRealm;
    }

    
    @Bean(name="simpleCookie")
    public SimpleCookie getSimpleCookie(){
        SimpleCookie simpleCookie = new SimpleCookie();
        simpleCookie.setName("rememberMe");
        simpleCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        simpleCookie.setMaxAge(7*24*60*60);
        return simpleCookie ;
    }

    
    @Bean(name="cookieRememberMeManager")
    @DependsOn({"simpleCookie"})
    public CookieRememberMeManager getCookieRememberMeManager(SimpleCookie simpleCookie){
        CookieRememberMeManager cookieRememberMeManager = new CookieRememberMeManager();
        cookieRememberMeManager.setCookie(simpleCookie);
        cookieRememberMeManager.setCipherKey(Base64.decode("2AvVhdsgUs0FSA3SDFAdag=="));
        return cookieRememberMeManager ;
    }

    

    @Bean(name = "securityManager")
    @DependsOn({"adminRealm","ehCacheManager","cookieRememberMeManager"})
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager getDefaultWebSecurityManager(AdminRealm realm, EhCacheManager ehCacheManager,CookieRememberMeManager cookieRememberMeManager) {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager defaultWebSecurityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        defaultWebSecurityManager.setRealm(realm);
        defaultWebSecurityManager.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager);
        defaultWebSecurityManager.setRememberMeManager(cookieRememberMeManager);
        return defaultWebSecurityManager;
    }

    
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAAP = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
        defaultAAP.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return defaultAAP;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("securityManager")
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(SecurityManager securityManager) {
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        return authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
    }

}
```

my pom.xml entry for shiro :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring-boot-web-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The project compile successfully but  i'm getting the above error while trying to access the web app, i appreciate any hemp or suggestion.

Error starting Tomcat context. Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'filterShiroFilterRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shiro/spring/config/web/autoconfigure/ShiroWebFilterConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'filterShiroFilterRegistrationBean' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'shiroFilterFactoryBean' available
```

Comment: Can you create a sample project on github to check the issue, someone might need a sample project for quick debug.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **@Configuration** annotations to the class,like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try changing the name of your bean from `@Bean(name="shiroFilter")` to `@Bean(name="shiroFilterFactoryBean")`.